Not able to store data in mongodb compass from docker container
I create d a simple todo list app using mern stack which take data from users and store in mongodb database it works fine on devlopment even with frontend and backend but when when i created a docker container with docker composite file it works properly opening and everything but it doesn't  store in my local mongodb compass GUI any one know why
??
front end code 

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import  Axios from 'axios'
import './App.css'

const App = () => {

  const[username,setusername] = useState("");
  const[password,setpassword] = useState("");



  const add = ()=>{
  Axios.post("http://localhost:4500/api/v1/addusers",{
    username:username,
    password:password
  }).then(()=>{
    alert("Data added successfully")
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
  }


  return (
    <>
 <div className='form1'>
  <input placeholder='Enter the username here' onChange={(e)=>{setusername(e.target.value)}}></input>
  <input placeholder='Enter the password here' onChange={(e)=>{setpassword(e.target.value)}}></input>
  <button onClick={add}>Submit</button>
 </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

package.json file

{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.9",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.15.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^9.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.12.0",
    "vite": "^6.0.1"
  }
}





//backend code 

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MONGOOSEURI = process.env.MONGODBURL

const connectDB = ()=>{
    try {
        mongoose.connect(`${MONGOOSEURI}`).then(()=>{
            console.log("Database connection successfully")
        }).catch(()=>{
            console.log("Database connection failed")
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB;

package.json file

{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.7",
    "express": "^4.21.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.9.1"
  },
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}


Data to be stored in mongodb compass GUI
